# Adding table rows from JSON result with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am fetching some data from the backend and it gives me a JSON result. Console logs work, so it is retrieving the data just fine. I need to get specific data and dynamically add that to a table as values in some inputs that are held in table cells and there are two cells per row. How can I achieve this with Vue and/or Javascript?

JSON EXAMPLE

```
[
{
Id: 1,
Type: "S"
},
{
Id: 2,
Type: "B"
}
]
```

JS

```
myMethod: function () {
            var res = this;
            var table = $('#tableID');
            fetch('/Contr/Get', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (data) {
                    res.id = data.Id;
                    res.type = data.Type;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var object = data[i];
                        $('#tableID').append(`<tr>
                            <td><input v-for='item in data' type="text" :value="{{ item.Id }}" /></td>
                            <td><input v-for='item in data' type="text" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="2" :value="{{ item.Type }}" /></td>
                    </tr >`)
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: if you're using jquery to add elements to a page, you're using vuejs wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what Vue's `v-for` is for.

Set up your template like this with table rows for each item

```html
<table id="tableID">
  <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.Id">
    <td>
      <input type="text" :value="item.Id" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="text-align: right;" maxlength="2" :value="item.Type" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in the `<script>` section

```js
data: () => ({
  items: [] // initialise to an empty array
}),
methods: {
  async myMethod () {
    const res = await fetch('/Contr/Get', { /* whatever */)
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw res
    }
    this.items = await res.json() // assign the response array to "items"
  }
}
```

When you execute `myMethod` and the AJAX call resolves, your table will be updated with whatever data comes back in the response.

Comment: Thank you so much, Phil! This explained just what I needed and it was done in a way that fits in cleanly with the code I already have. Great stuff!

Answer (score -1):

You should use `v-for` directive on a `<tr>` element within template to loop over your data: https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html